# NotSerializableException on GroupLayout, but no GroupLayout used

Tags: java, swing, serialization

I'm working on a piece of code where I'm required to extend a JPanel and then serialize it's result. However on attempting to serialize it I get this error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.GroupLayout
```

The code for the object I'm trying to serialize is as follows:

```
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel
{

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJPanel
     */
    public NewJPanel()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents()
    {
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Trying to serialize a plain, non-extended JPanel works but the extended one does not. As you can see, there is no usage of GroupLayout and the panel instead defaults to FlowLayout. Even setting it explicitly does not prevent this. Can anyone tell me why this happens and how I might fix or work around this issue?

Comment: There is code inside the initComponents() method, generated by your IDE, and using GroupLayout. Expand the method, and you'll see. Don't serialize UI widgets. Serialize data. And don't use Java serialization for long term storage. It's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: As you can see, the initCoponents() method is expanded and actually empty. I would serialize just the data if I could but it is one of the requirements for this assignment that I serialize the entire object. I would talk to the teacher if I could, but he doesn't respond to email, and we only see him once a week.

Comment: So your panel doesn't contain anything? Open this Java file with any other text editor (Notepad, vi, whatever).

Comment: Correct. It doesn't contain anything even when viewed in Notepad++. If it's any help, the compiler I'm using is Nebeans 8.2

Comment: Then something must set the layou of the panel from the outside. If you want help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: You were right! It was actually being modified by the JFrame form in the code that made an instance of it and initialized it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the JFrame form builder on Netbeans snuck in setting the JPannel's layout manager to GroupLayout when I dropped it into the JFrame instead of leaving it as the layout that I had specified in the JPannel's code as would be sensible.